# How to remove an object from and object array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
[{LanguageMedium: "Sinhala Medium"}, {Subject: "English"}, {Type: "Past"}]
```

From this array object how to remove the object where object key is "LanguageMedium"

Comment: This question is edited as there is an change in the question

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your Object keys using a [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop and use the `delete` keyword when you get a match.

```js
const obj = { name: 'mary', name: 'john' } 

for (const key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === 'mary') {
    delete obj[key]
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#find` to iterate through keys in the object and find out the key whose value is `Sinhala Medium`. You can get keys using `Object.keys()`. Then you can use `delete` to remove the key from your object.

```js
var obj = { LanguageMedium: "Sinhala Medium", Subject: "English", Type: "Past" },
    key = Object.keys(obj).find(k => obj[k] === 'Sinhala Medium');
delete obj[key];
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all the keys to match the key to be deleted like the following:

```js
var obj = { LanguageMedium: "Sinhala Medium", Subject: "English", Type: "Past" }

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k){
  if (obj[k] == 'Sinhala Medium'){
    delete obj[k];
  }
});
console.log(obj);
```